# Blender fullscreen OS X El Capitan

Tags: osx

Good day everyone,

blender v2.76b is working perfectly fine in window mode on my MacBook (OS X El Capitan 10.11.1) but when I am switching to the fullscreen mode... It is working very slow and freezing all the time. I was trying to change some settings in the preferences but no luck.

Is there any solution for this? Thank you for your attention

Comment: I get the same issue on my MacBook. I have just done a bug report on blender developers website. Let's wait.

Answer (score 1):

it works perfectly fine for me but I would suggest reinstalling blender. The macbook i use also has laggy animations sometimes so i restarted the computer and it turned out that my ram was full